# Add ToolkitScriptManager to master page

Tags: toolkitscriptmanager

Adding the ToolkitScriptManager to master page is enough for content pages?
Or should I add ToolkitScriptManager to each and every page including master page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add ToolkitScriptManager to master page under `<form>` tag.